# On hover include more detail about object PVIZ

Tags: javascript, html, css, visualization, bioinformatics

I am using the genentech/pviz github to display proteins and peptides. I do not have enough rep to create a new tag but I think it would be a good idea to make a pviz tag related to this github : https://github.com/Genentech/pviz. I have been using this github a lot but I cannot find much information on it on stack overflow because there is not tag. I have gotten a nice graphic and have used a hover feature in the css portion to change the color of the rectangle when hovered over. However, I want to display additionally information about the peptide and or protein when hovering over it as well.

```css
g.feature.psms.normal:hover rect.feature {
    fill: black;

}
```

```
  seqEntry.addFeatures(fts.map(function(ft) {
                return {
                    //we could also use te categoryType property, for height purpose, but not grouping purpose
                    category : 'psms',
                    type : ft[2], //This would be "normal" in most cases
                    start : ft[0],
                    end : ft[1],
                    text : '',
                }
            }));
```

I am not sure how to display information because I cannot find any good documentation. How would I be able to display text when hovering over the peptide rectangles?

Comment: I answered my own question down below but it is specific to my example please answer with a broader approach if you have one

Comment: Also as I explained in my question I want to add a tag called PViz because related to the github linked in the question but I do not have enough rep. If you have enough rep please create one so users can find more information on here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The features that I used were SVG rectangles and after playing around for a bit I have found a solution using JS. 
First create a MouseoverCallback on the specific feature types you want:

```
pviz.FeatureDisplayer.addMouseoverCallback(['normal', 'oxidize'], function(ft) {
                mouseOveredFT = ft;
                var el = $('#output-mouse-over');
                el.empty();
                el.html('<pre>' + "This peptide starts at: " + JSON.stringify(ft['start']) + ", ends at: " +
                JSON.stringify(ft['end']) + ", and has the sequence: " + JSON.stringify(ft['text']) + '</pre>')
            }).addMouseoutCallback(['normal', 'oxidize'], function(ft) {
                mouseOveredFT = undefined;

            });
```

The el.html part is what you want to display. After where you create the SVG rectangle amke sure to add:

```
 xChangeCallback : function(pStart, pEnd) {
                var str = 'cursor at ' + pStart.toFixed(1) + ' - ' + pEnd.toFixed(1);
                if (mouseOveredFT !== undefined) {
                    str += '<strong> -> on FT'
                }

                $('#output-x-change').html(str);
            }
```

Then in your html document write:

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="span2" >
                <strong>Information about peptide</strong>
            </div><div class="span10" id="output-mouse-over"></div>
        </div>
<!--        <div class="row">-->
<!--            <div class="span2" >-->
<!--                <strong>xchange</strong>-->
<!--            </div><div class="span10" id="output-x-change"></div>-->
<!--        </div>-->
```

I commented out the second part because I did not need that but the second part allows you to display the location of your cursor. Meanwhile the first part display what you put in the el.html part. I hope this makes sense but I doubt many people will need help with this. I have found nothing online about this. :(